# To be versus have in their passive forms?

Tags: passive-voice

'He'd only had it told to him by the townspeople'.  What is the difference between this passive construction and if it had said, 'He was only told...'?

Comment: Both are passive, but there are a few differences between the two. For one thing, the first is in perfect tense, the second is simple tense.

Comment: Thanks.  I see the past perfect is more accurate here as it specifies a continuous telling by the townspeople (in the next sentence).  The trick then is to spot the tenses to aid the research.

Comment: Past perfect sometimes indicates continuous action, but more often it simply suggests that some past action is still relevant to the present time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are in the passive voice, in that in each sentence, the subject is being acted upon (passive voice). If you want to change the voice to the active voice, you could word each sentence as follows:

> Only the townspeople had told him about it.
>
> Only the townspeople told him about it.

As for my putting the word *only* before the word *townspeople*, I did that because the *only* modifies *townspeople*, not *him*. Compare the following two sentences:

> We only gave the award to him.

Here, the sentence sounds as if "we" were the only ones to give him a reward. Now, if that's what you want to say, fine. If, however, you want to single "him" out, then put the *only* next to him, as in

> We gave the award only to him.

Meaning: He's the only person to whom we gave the award.

Comment: Cheers, that helpfully illuminates the passive usage for me again.  But in this case, the guy didn't see an incident himself and so 'he'd only had it told to him by the townspeople'.  I'd have written this as, 'he'd only been told by the townspeople'.  Is there a difference between using the verb have here and including the pronoun 'him', and using 'to be' and omitting the pronoun?

Comment: @RoySpivey: So, the emphasis is on TOLD? As in the townspeople witnessed something he did not witness, so he was relying on their having TOLD him. In other words, they did not show him a video of the incident or refer him to a particular person who was intimately involved in the incident. They just TOLD him about it. Is that correct? If so, I need a bit more information about the two options you've laid out for me in your comment. I'm a little uncertain about what you mean by asking if there's a difference between "using the verb HAS with the pronoun HIM, and TO BE without HIM.

Comment: The full context is: '...Granier had come out of the barbershop across the street too late to see this.  He'd only had it told to him by the townspeople...'.  So the only I think applies to told, yes.  But my main question is are both of these passive versions grammatically correct and what is the difference between them?  1)'he'd only had it told to him by the townspeople' and 2)'he'd only been told by the townspeople'.  I'm now thinking it's just a slight difference of emphasis, 1)stressing his not having witnessed it and 2) maybe implying, as you did, that the townspeople used other methods

Comment: So the former makes more sense and is clearer in this context?

Comment: @RoySpivey: Yeah, I like your version #1. And the passive voice works just fine, as far as I can tell.